# center big Logoh1 in the middle of navigation bar menu

Tags: css, navigationbar

I'm trying to get this but is impossible.

I've a code pen with to examples:

[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/elcollage_com/pen/YyBjyG)

```css
.logoh1 {
  text-indent:-99999px;
  width: 338px;
  height: 340px;
  background:   url('http://www.elcollage.com/isra/etxepare/prueba-logo.jpg');
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .1;
}


body {
background: #fff;
font-family: arial;
}


header {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}

nav li{
display: inline-block;
padding: 40px 30px 40px 0;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) {
padding-right: 100px;
}

nav li:nth-child(3) {
padding-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
      <li>CLASES de ACORDEÓN</li>
      <li>PROFESORADO</li>
      <li>ACORDEONES</li>
      <li>CONTACTO</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="logoh1"></div>
 </header>
</section>
```

and other:

[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/elcollage_com/pen/zveMav)

```css
.logoh1 {
  text-indent:-99999px;
  width: 338px;
  height: 340px;
  background:   url('http://www.elcollage.com/isra/etxepare/prueba-logo.jpg');
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .1;
}


body {
background: #fff;
font-family: arial;
}


header {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}

nav li{
display: inline-block;
padding: 40px 30px 40px 0;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <ul class="left">
      <li>CLASES de ACORDEÓN</li>
      <li>PROFESORADO</li>
   </ul>
    
   <ul class="right">
      <li>ACORDEONES</li>
      <li>CONTACTO</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="logoh1"></div>
 </header>
</section>
```

this two options works fine with little logos but no with a bigger.

Can everybody help me.

thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjGqoo

Comment: no. The logo must be in de midlle of menu navigation. Between <li>'s

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I don´t remember that the header width was so small for the big logo. I change the size to 1170px and I float-left and add a padding-left to the class right.

And know work it.

[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/elcollage_com/pen/rOPPbo)

```css
.logoh1 {
  text-indent:-99999px;
  width: 338px;
  height: 340px;
  background:   url('http://www.elcollage.com/isra/etxepare/prueba-logo.jpg');
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .1;
}


body {
background: #fff;
font-family: arial;
}


header {
width: 1170px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}

nav li{
display: inline-block;
padding: 40px 30px 40px 0;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 380px;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <ul class="left">
      <li>CLASES de ACORDEÓN</li>
      <li>PROFESORADO</li>
   </ul>
    
   <ul class="right">
      <li>ACORDEONES</li>
      <li>CONTACTO</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="logoh1"></div>
 </header>
</section>
```

thanks.